# CircleCI 2.0 testing with docker-compose and code checkout

Tags: docker-compose, circleci

This is my circle.yml:

```
version: 2
jobs:
  build:
    working_directory: /app
    docker:
      - image: docker:stable-git
  steps:
    - checkout
    - setup_remote_docker
    - run:
        name: Install dependencies
        command: |
          apk add --no-cache py-pip bash
          pip install docker-compose
    - run:
        name: Start service containers and run tests
        command: |
          docker-compose -f docker-compose.test.yml up -d db es redis
          docker-compose run web bash -c "cd myDir && ./manage.py test"
```

This works fine in that it brings up my service containers (db, es, redis) and I build a new image for my web container.  However, my working code is not inside the freshly built image (so "cd myDir" always fails).

I figure the following lines in my Dockerfile should make my code available when it's built but it appears that it doesn't work like that:

```
ENV APPLICATION_ROOT /app/
RUN mkdir -p $APPLICATION_ROOT
WORKDIR $APPLICATION_ROOT
ADD . $APPLICATION_ROOT
```

What am I doing wrong and how can I make my code available inside my test container?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

Use `COPY`, Your Dockerfile should look something like this.

> FROM image
>
> COPY . /opt/app
>
> WORKDIR "/opt/app"
>
> (More commands)
>
> ENTRYPOINT